# Are NumPy ndarrays truly mutable?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my first code snippet. When run, it doesn't throw an assertion error.

```
import numpy as np


this_arr = np.ones(10)

next_arr = this_arr

next_arr *= 2

assert np.array_equal(this_arr, next_arr)
```

Here is my second code snippet. When run, it does throw an assertion error.

```
import numpy as np


this_arr = np.ones(10)

next_arr = this_arr

next_arr = next_arr * 2

assert np.array_equal(this_arr, next_arr)
```

This behavior is confusing to me.

My understanding of the first code snippet is that I initialize the name `this_arr` to point to the value at some memory location. Then, when I initialize the name `next_arr` to point to the same value at the same memory location. Therefore, when I change the value pointed to by `next_arr`, the value pointed to by `this_arr` should also change. This behavior is the "Mutable-Presto-Chango," which was coined by Ned Batchelder [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

However, the second code snippet, does not behave this way. At first, I thought that maybe the `*=` operator somehow doesn't change the value's location in memory while the `*` operator does. But then I went back through the first snippet and found that the memory locations of `this_arr` and `next_arr` are different here too! Given that, how does the program "know" to change the values of `this_arr` to match those of the changed `next_arr`? Also, why doesn't the program "know" to change the values in the second code snippet?

Edit: As a followup question: So even though next_arr and this_arr have different memory locations, there is some underlying connection between the two that python has initialized?

Thanks!

Comment: "At first, I thought that maybe the *= operator somehow doesn't change the value's location in memory while the * operator does." You're correct, according to the [docs for augmented assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements): "when possible, the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead."

Comment: "My understanding of the first code snippet is that I initialize the name this_arr to point to the value at some memory location. " No, **that's never how anything works in Python**. It is extremely unhelpful to think in terms of *memory locations*. Python is a high level language. Your mental model should be about *objects*. You assigned a `numpy.ndarray` object to the variable `this_arr`.  Then you assign `next_array` to the object being referenced by `this_array`, *but immediately after* you assign *another* object to `next_array`, the one created by `next_arr = next_arr * 2`.

Comment: Or, IOW, `next_arr * 2` **isn't a mutation**. But `next_arr *= 2` is.

Comment: @jfaccioni Thanks for the comment! But, upon checking with my debugger, this_arr and next_arr have different memory addresses in both snippets. Given that, how can this_arr change when next_arr changes in the first snippet?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the comment! So even though next_arr and this_arr have different memory locations, there is some underlying connection between the two that python has initialized? And this is broken when I create a new ndarray object with next_arr = next_arr * 2, but not with next_arr *= 2 because the latter is a mutation?

Comment: In your first example, they have the same memory location, in the second example, they do not. How are you getting different memory locations, provide a reproducible example of how you verify that (again, **really** not the best way to think about things, they are *the same object* or *different objects*).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am new to python, so I may be doing this wrong. Here is my procedure for getting two different memory addresses with my first snippet. My IDE is PyCharm.
1. Add a breakpoint to the line "next_arr *= 2".
2. Run PyCharm's debugger on my script.
3. Once the solver stops at the breakpoint, I expand the "next_arr" and "this_arr" variables in the debugger console.
4. Then, for both "next_arr" and "this_arr," I click "Show Value" next to the "array" object contained within each variable.
5. I got: 0x000001D7EF6189C8 and 0x000001D7EF618DC8 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to talk in terms of objects and references, rather than values.  So I would describe your first code as:

This creates a `ndarray` object, and assigns it (or a reference to it) to `this_arr`:

```
this_arr = np.ones(10)
```

and assign the same reference to `next_arr`:

```
next_arr = this_arr
```

So `next_arr` and `this_arr` reference the same object.

Then do an 'in-place' change to the array object. It doesn't matter which name is used.

```
next_arr *= 2
```

The two names still reference the same array object.  (under the covers does `*=` some buffering, but the array object and data buffer location remain the same).  Another mutuable change would be `next_arr[1] = 10` (this would true for list objects as well).

With

```
next_arr = next_arr * 2
```

the multiplication makes a new array object.  That is assigned to `next_arr`, breaking any links with the previously reference object (which `this_arr` still references).

If `id(this_arr)` and `id(next_arr)` are the same, then the reference the object.  Roughly the `id` is a location - but not the same as a pointer in `c`.  But be wary about comparing the ids over time; they may be reused.

`arr.__array_interface__` is another handy tool. If has a `data` key that tells us where the underlying data buffer of an array is located.  But to understand that you need to know something about how arrays are stored, and the distinction between `view` and `copy`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I replaced my call to assert with assert(id(this_arr) == id(next_arr)). The first code snippet resulted in the same ID value for each array, and the second code snippet resulted in different ID values for each array. That checks out!

Comment: Do you know what the difference between the ID value and the memory value given by PyCharm's debugger? Although the ID values of the two arrays in the first code snippet are identical, the procedure I described in the comments below my question still produces different values in memory.

Comment: I don't use `pycharm` so can't say what it's showing.

Answer (score -1):

when you initialize next_arr=this_arr what it actually does is it copies the values of this_arr's location to a new location of next_arr. Its my understanding about this code or else this behaviour won't be possible

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. In order for the first code snippet to not throw an error, this would imply that after performing next_arr *= 2, its values are copied back to this_arr. Is that correct?

Comment: With `initialize next_arr=this_arr` there's no copying of values.  This is just a simple Python variable assignment.

Comment: This is not correct, or at the very least, not stated clearly enough